# $\|f \otimes g\|_{L^p} \leq \|f\|_{L^p} \|g\|_{L^p}$ for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$

Tags: integration, inequality, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

I am looking to prove the inequality
$$\|f \otimes g\|_{L^p} \leq \|f\|_{L^p} \|g\|_{L^p}$$
for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Here $f$ takes values in a Banach space $X_1$ and $g$ takes values in a Banach space $X_2$.

I suspect this is true from the Cauchy-Schwartz like identity that holds for operators
$$\|S \otimes T\| \leq \|S\| \|T\|$$
that is outlined in the answer to this question [Norm of a tensor product of operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349585/norm-of-a-tensor-product-of-operators), but I am not completely sure. Is this inequality true? Should it instead be Holder like as in
$$\|f \otimes g\|_{L^p} \leq \|f\|_{L^q} \|g\|_{L^r}, \quad \frac1p = \frac1q + \frac1r?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $S,T \in X_1 \times X_2$, $\|S \otimes T\| = \|S\|\|T\|$ (see the post you shared), so for all real number $t$, $\|f(t) \otimes g(t)\| = \|f(t)\|\|g(t)\|$ and by Hölder, if $p,q,r$ are such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{r}$,
\begin{align*}
\|f \otimes g\|_{L^r} & = \|t \mapsto \|f(t) \otimes g(t)\|\|_{L^r}\\
& = \|t \mapsto \|f(t)\|\|g(t)\|\|_{L^r}\\
& \leqslant \|t \mapsto \|f(t)\|\|_{L^p}\|t \mapsto \|g(t)\|\|_{L^q}\\
& = \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}.
\end{align*}
The first inequality, however, is not true in general. Take for example $p = 2$, $f_0 \in X_1$ of norm $1$, $g_0 \in X_2$ of norm $1$ and,
$$
f : t \mapsto t^{-1/3}e^{-t^2}f_0, \qquad g : t \mapsto t^{-1/3}e^{-t^2}g_0.
$$
Then, $\|f \otimes g\|_{L^2} = \left\|t \mapsto (t^{-1/3}e^{-t^2})^2\right\|_{L^2} = \sqrt{\|t^{-4/3}e^{-4t^2}\|_{L^1}} = +\infty$ while $\|f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2} = \|t \mapsto t^{-1/3}e^{-t^2}\|_{L^2}^2 = \|t \mapsto t^{-2/3}e^{-2t^2}\|_{L^2} < +\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much!